# How do handle a binary division that starts by 0? in a CRC calculation

Tags: computer-science, binary, network

im facing a new case of binary division and i would like to know how to manage it. My problems is that it starts by 0 and i'm not sure how to handle that.
NOTE: this is a CRC calculation problem and M' = 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

i have:
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 / 1 0 0 0 0 1

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Just as in decimal, the leading $0$s can be ignored.

Comment: even if this is for a CRC calculation ? and the message' = 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0?

Comment: If you are just dividing, yes.  If you are doing some other operation, you need to define it.  I think of CRC as more like a multiply, then add.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) you are XORing the bits with the "divisor", not dividing.  In that case you should do just that-write the "divisor" under the leftmost bits of the message and do the bitwise XOR.  As I read the article you align the leftmost $1$ of the divisor with the leftmost $1$ of the message, which corresponds to ignoring the leading $0$s

Comment: It is division in polynomial ring with coefficients in GF(2). XOR functions as addition as well as subtraction. Here it acts like subtraction. Normal rules for polynomial division apply including skipping leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: just skip to the first bit with value 1**

In the CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) algorithm for generating code words, we follow a process called "modulo-2 division".

This is basically applying XOR instead of subtraction.

In CRC, the value to be XORd, is dependent only on the MSB (most significant bit, i.e., the left most bit) of the dividend at the step.

If you have a 0 as the MSB at any step, you XOR the dividend with 0s, otherwise you XOR with the divisor. This essentially means that leading zeroes can be ignored/skipped (in non-hardware simulation)

The same logic applies to the start of the problem too. If your dividend has leading zeroes from the beginning, just skip to the first bit with value 1.

Disclosure: I haven't studied the theoretical derivation behind this method nor worked with real implementations on the networks.

My source: https://www.fishercom.xyz/division-multiplexing/cyclic-redundancy-check-crc.html